# Queries of checkbox on octobercms/laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, octobercms

I would like to know how i can get the current status of checkbox without saving the model in octbercms or laravel. Thanks. The following is what i would like to do:

```
 public function button_pressed(){     
    if(checked){
        //do something
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if a checkbox is checked you basically have to check if the input exists, so using the request object:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function button_pressed( Request $request ){
    if( $request->has('checkbox_name') ){
        // checkbox is check
    } else {
        // checkbox is NOT check
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
public function button_pressed(){
    if( request()->has('checkbox_name') ){
        // checkbox is check
    } else {
       // checkbox is NOT check
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi TheFallen, Thanks for your reply. But i'm has the following error when i try to use the code. argument 1 passed to must be an instance of illuminate\http\request

Comment: @tan is your **button_pressed** method inside a controller and do you add the **use** at the top?

Comment: Hi TheFallen, Yes, i have added Illuminate\Http\Request; at the top. I have tried  button_pressed method  on both controller and model but is not working for me. Thanks

Comment: HI TheFallen, It's giving me an error of undefined function for request(). Other suggestion? Thanks. would appreciate your help

Comment: @tan how do you access the request object inside your controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114612/discussion-between-tan-and-thefallen).